# Call on different CSS transitionEnd Events

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-transitions

I am using CSS transitions to animate two Elements inside a Slider for this particular portion of the code.
One is a loading image (gif) and the other one is the slider.

Since there is two elements to be animated via transition, I want to listen to two different transitionEnd events. One for the loading image and one for the slider.

I am currently using this code :

```
 base._initStage = function() {
                base._initListeners();

                //checks if all images in all slides are finished loading
                base.imagesLoaded( function($images, $proper, $broken) {
                    var $loading = globals.$pixslider.find('.loading');


                // bind transitionEnd on $loading element
                // PROBLEM : This calls alert('test') which is supposed to be called after adjusting $pixslider height
                    $loading.css('opacity', 0).one( transitionEnd, function() {
                        base.loadActiveSlide();
                    });
                });
            };

            base.loadActiveSlide = function() {
                var $active = globals.$activeSlide;

                // adjust $pixslider height depending on active slide's height
                globals.$pixslider.height( $active.height() );

                // bind transitionEnd on $pixslider element
                globals.$pixslider.one( transitionEnd, function() {
                    // PROBLEM : This gets called on end of loadings transitionEnd
                    alert('test');
                });

            };
```

I am using .one() method of jquery to listen to transitionEnd once since it kinda gets called several times if I use .bind() or .on().

The problem is that alert('test') gets called on transitionEnd of the $loading element which isn't what I want because I want it to happen on transitionEnd of the $pixslider element.

Am I not getting something about the .one() method or is this a common issue on the transitionEnd event?

I am using the modernizr way of sniffing the event :

```
var transEndEventNames = {
        'WebkitTransition': 'webkitTransitionEnd',
        'MozTransition': 'transitionend',
        'OTransition': 'oTransitionEnd otransitionend',
        'msTransition': 'MSTransitionEnd',
        'transition': 'transitionend'
    }, transitionEnd = transEndEventNames[Modernizr.prefixed('transition')];
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not an issue with `.one`. You just need to examine the properties of the event object when it fires. Also, there's a quicker, slicker way that does without modernizr. Just write:

```
globals.$pixslider.one('webkitTransitionEnd OTransitionEnd transitionend', function(event) {
    console.log(event);
    console.log(event.currentTarget);
    // some conditional logic depending on which element is firing the event
});
```

Also, I'm pretty sure there's no need for `MSTransitionEnd`, since IE9 didn't support transitions and IE10 supports them unprefixed. Modernizr is wrong on this. I've filed a ticket with them